# How can I move the EndIconDrawable to End|Bottom in a multiline TextInputLayout

Tags: android, material-design, android-textinputlayout

I'm trying to add an EndIconDrawable to a multiline TextInputLayout with gravity end|bottom. The default position of the EndIconDrawable is end|center. 
Now my question: Is this possible with the default settings of the material element or do I have to implement this as a CustomElement.

This is my current source for this Element:

```xml
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Theme.MyApp.BoxedLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:hint="Outlinebox"
        app:endIconCheckable="true"
        app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_mic_black_24dp"
        app:endIconMode="custom">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:minLines="5"
            android:textColor="@color/blue_grey_900" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

and this is the style part:

```xml
    <style name="Theme.MyApp.BoxedLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
        <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/blue_grey_900</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeWidth">2dp</item>
    </style>
```

This picture shows how the result should look like:
[TextInputLayout with multiline and EndIcon on BottomEnd (edited)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z17P7.png)

Comment: did you find a working solution for your question?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet. I also don't have time to actively work on this problem at the moment.

Comment: @JU5T1C3 Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem and found out that the end icon is a CheckableImageButton with the ID *com.google.android.material.R.id.text_input_end_icon* placed inside a FrameLayout. So just customize the FrameLayout.Params as needed.

[image]

Check the following code snippet:

```
// using viewbinding
       private ActivityCommentBinding mBinding;

// change the end icon gravity
       FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mBinding.commentTextLayout
                .findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.text_input_end_icon)
                .getLayoutParams();
        params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
        mBinding.commentTextLayout
                .findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.text_input_end_icon)
                        .setLayoutParams(params);
```

The runtime result:

[image]

I also opened a GitHub feature request [here.](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/2777)